# Can I revalidate my EASA PPL outside the EU in a non-EASA aircraft?

Tags: easa-regulations, pilot-certification, ppl

I'm trying to re-validate my EASA PPL licence, registered with the Hungarian CAA. I asked the CAA but I did not get a clear answer.

I meet the criteria for re-validation based on experience, but it also requires minimally one hour refresher training with and EASA (FI) or (CFI). I can not travel to the EU due to COVID measures.

Can I fly outside of EU with an EASA FI for refreshing training on a non-EASA registered aircraft?

Comment: You'll need to trawl through https://www.easa.europa.eu/ if nobody can answer directly, but it might also help to specify where abouts in the world you currently are. I know I've certainly heard of EASA instructors operating in  the US for pretty much exactly your requirement.